# Restrict specific date format Data into Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I Have a table called Sur_Data and the data looks like:

```
ID     SV_Date
258    13/01/2010
569    15/02/2011
695    26/05/2010
745    12/06/2010
```

Now I want to select the ID's from that table and insert into another table so we are using something like:

```
Insert into Surdate(ID)
Select ID from Sur_Data
where ISDATE(SV_Date) = 1
```

Since the format in SV_Date is different it is not inserting any records into Surdate table.

So I am trying to see is there a way that we could restrict the data in Sur_Data table to have only date's that are in MM/DD/YYYY format.So whenever they try to insert records of different format it should throw an error.

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Why not use an appropriate [datetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) (or [date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) for 2008) data type for the `SV_Date` column?

Comment: @JoeStefanelli I am but dates like 26/05/2010,15/02/2011  will also be inserted but when I use isdate() on those it will return 0 and will not be inserted into another table

Comment: How about having a trigger on the table which converts the date into required format before inserting/updating?

Comment: @Peter - A datetime column would not have a "format". I think that you are confused about something. If your column is giving you something that says it's not a date then you're not using a datetime column datatype.

Comment: @Peter: a `DATETIME` column is a `DATETIME` column is a `DATETIME` column - it doesn't have any notion of a "format" or anything - it's just a value. The formatting **only** comes into play when **showing** such data, e.g. in SQL Server Mgmt Studio or in your app. See [Demystifying the SQL Server DATETIME type](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2004/datetime-datatype) for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** for example 2 & 3, ANSI WARNINGS must be off.

`IS_DATE` function is influenced by `DATEFORMAT` setting for current SQL Server session/connection.

**Example 1:**

```
DECLARE @d1 VARCHAR(25) = '26/05/2010'
        ,@d2 VARCHAR(25) = '15/02/2011';

PRINT '*****Test 1*****'        
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
SELECT  ISDATE(@d1), ISDATE(@d2);       

PRINT '*****Test 2*****'        
SET DATEFORMAT MDY;
SELECT  ISDATE(@d1), ISDATE(@d2);
```

Results:

```
*****Test 1*****

----------- -----------
1           1

(1 row(s) affected)

*****Test 2*****

----------- -----------
0           0

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Now, you can see how `DATEFORMAT` influences `ISDATE` function.
Instead of `ISDATE` function you can use `CONVERT` function with different [date/time styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). If a `[n][var]char` value doesn't have the selected style then `CONVERT` function will return NULL. For `dd/mm/yyyy` values (british) can be used style 103 and  for `mm/dd/yyyy` values (U.S.) can be used style 101.

**Example 2:**

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;
SET ARITHABORT OFF;

DECLARE @Results TABLE
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY
    ,SV_Date VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT  @Results 
VALUES
 (258,    '13/01/2010')
,(569,    '15/02/2011')
,(695,    '26/05/2010')
,(745,    '12/06/2010');

SELECT  *
        ,ISDATE(r.SV_Date) [IS_DATETIME]
        ,CONVERT(DATETIME,r.SV_Date,103) [IS_DATETIME British/French style=dd/mm/yyyy]
        ,CONVERT(DATETIME,r.SV_Date,101) [IS_DATETIME U.S. style=mm/dd/yyyy]
        ,CASE 
            WHEN CONVERT(DATETIME,r.SV_Date,103) IS NOT NULL AND CONVERT(DATETIME,r.SV_Date,101) IS NULL THEN 'IS_DMY'
            WHEN CONVERT(DATETIME,r.SV_Date,103) IS NULL AND CONVERT(DATETIME,r.SV_Date,101) IS NOT NULL THEN 'IS_MDY'
            WHEN CONVERT(DATETIME,r.SV_Date,103) IS NOT NULL AND CONVERT(DATETIME,r.SV_Date,101) IS NOT NULL THEN 'IS_DMY_OR_MDY'
            WHEN CONVERT(DATETIME,r.SV_Date,103) IS NULL AND CONVERT(DATETIME,r.SV_Date,101) IS NULL THEN 'IS_NOT_DMY_OR_MDY'
        END
FROM    @Results r;
```

Results:

```
ID          SV_Date              IS_DATETIME IS_DATETIME British/French style=dd/mm/yyyy IS_DATETIME U.S. style=mm/dd/yyyy 
----------- -------------------- ----------- ------------------------------------------- --------------------------------- -----------------
258         13/01/2010           0           2010-01-13 00:00:00.000                     NULL                              IS_DMY
569         15/02/2011           0           2011-02-15 00:00:00.000                     NULL                              IS_DMY
695         26/05/2010           0           2010-05-26 00:00:00.000                     NULL                              IS_DMY
745         12/06/2010           1           2010-06-12 00:00:00.000                     2010-12-06 00:00:00.000           IS_DMY_OR_MDY
```

Now, if you want to check SV_Date values for `mm/dd/yyyy` format (style 101 - U.S.) then you can use a `CHECK` constraint like this:

**Example 3:**

```
DECLARE @Results2 TABLE
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY
    ,SV_Date VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    ,CHECK( CONVERT(DATETIME,SV_Date,101) IS NOT NULL )
);
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;
INSERT  @Results2 
VALUES  (258,    '13/01/2010');
INSERT  @Results2 
VALUES  (569,    '15/02/2011');
INSERT  @Results2 
VALUES  (695,    '26/05/2010');
INSERT  @Results2 
VALUES  (745,    '12/06/2010');
SELECT  *
FROM    @Results2;
```

Results:

```
ID          SV_Date
----------- --------------------
745         12/06/2010

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Observations:
If you want to find current `DATEFORMAT` setting (current session) then you can use [`sys.dm_exec_sessions` view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176013.aspx):

```
SELECT  s.date_format, s.date_first
FROM    sys.dm_exec_sessions s
WHERE   s.session_id = @@SPID
```

Comment: +1 clever use of the convert function with datetime. I never realized it had the capability.

Comment: @Bogdan When I execute them I am getting errors Like: Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 7
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: What have you tested ? Did you changed the data type ?

Comment: @Bogdan I am sorry for the above comment. But this is what Exactly I am looking for. Thank you so much. Appreciate all your help on this.

Comment: @Peter: tell me what example did you have run ? Example 1 / 2 / 3 ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean I ran Example 2 and 3 but Example 3 is what I am looking for

Comment: @Peter: run this 2 queries and tell me the results: `SELECT db.is_ansi_warnings_on 
FROM master.sys.databases  db
WHERE db.database_id = DB_ID();
SELECT SESSIONPROPERTY('ANSI_WARNINGS')`

Comment: @BogdanSahlean the first query Returned 0 and the second query returned 1

Comment: Before every example (2 & 3) execute this statement [SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190368%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx). To be more precise, before every INSERT, ANSI_WARNINGS must be OFF.

Comment: How could this have even been run without encountering errors?!
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 119
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The only way this works is on SQL 2012 or above with TRY_CONVERT
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx

Comment: @JJS: What example causes you troubles ?

Comment: See first note: "Edit:". And also [TRY_PARSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx).

Comment: @BogdanSahlean example 2 failed for me with mssql 2008 r2 SP3 standard as the engine.

Comment: Thanks @BogdanSahlean, I confirm this works. I updated your answer to include SET ARITHABORT.

Comment: @JJS: The usage of these settings (ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT) with OFF has many downsides: for indexed view, indexes on computed columns, filtered indexes and for (some) XML methods / xqueries these settings and others are recommended to be ON. Please see [Required SET Options for Indexed Views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx) section.For SQL2012+, one simple solution is to use TRY_PARSE or TRY_CONVERT.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean i agree on all points. would you like me to remove my edit of your answer? appologies for not asking first

Comment: @JJS: It's fine. My last comment is just a note to be clear what are the pros and the cons of these changes / to have a complete picture of consequences of these changes.

Answer (score 1):

To strictly answer the question, you could create a function (CLR or TSQL) and apply that as a column constraint/check.

But as @joe Stefanelli correctly points out, store it as a datetime data type and let the client handle the presentation format.

### Edit

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx

```
ALTER TABLE
    dbo.Sur_Data 
WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT ck_dateFormatted CHECK (dbo.VerifyDateFormat(SV_Date) = 1) ;
```

Which assumes you've defined a function that returns 1 if the format matches the expectation.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I apply constraint/check?

Comment: Updated with example and link to alter table syntax